# Book about escaping an ice age using suspended animation

Tags: story-identification, books

The book was about a group of folks traveling to Wisconsin to escape the next ice age. The facility they were going to was underground and in it they would be put into suspended animation for the duration of the coming ice age.

I think the main character's name was Harry Munson. I think it was pre-1980.

Comment: There is the book Fallen Angels. One of the settings is Milwaukee, Wisconsin. It is Ice Age related, but not pre-1980.

Comment: Looks like you must mean the [Niven, Pournelle, Flynn](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/100364.Fallen_Angels) one. I don't think that's the one. Doesn't seem to have anything about underground suspended animation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost definitely [*The Odyssey Project*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?256654) (1989) by Lawrence De Marino.

The protagonist is Ted Amundsen, and I guess "Amundsen" is close to "Munson."

The premise is that the U.S. government has figured out that the coming ice age will be the worst ever, and there won't be any land warm enough to grow food for thousands of years.  This is still secret, and under cover of creating a plan to migrate to warmer climates, they have started a project to freeze people for tens of thousands of years.

The project is located in Wisconsin:

> "This is Project Odyssey, and we're in south-central Wisconsin," Carlyle answered.
>
> Amundson was stunned. He had expected to hear "Project Migrant" again. "And exactly what is Project Odyssey?"
>
> Carlyle paused for only a second. "It's a research project to perfect suspended animation. That's what the cylinders are for."
>
> "Suspended animation? Explain."
>
> "The concept?"
>
> "No, Doctor, I'm familiar with the concept. Why are you perfecting suspended animation?"
>
> [...]
>
> "All right, all right. Do you know about the ice age?" he squealed.
>
> "Yes."
>
> "Do you know about Operation Migrant?"
>
> "Yes."
>
> "All right, that makes it easy," the doctor said, regaining some of his composure. "Operation Migrant is a diversion.  The ice age will be much more severe than first thought.  The entire planet will be uninhabitable, and there eventually will be no Green Belt. So Project Odyssey has become our only hope for survival.  Suspended animation for selected individuals—government leaders, scientists..."
>
> "The people being kidnapped," Kelly interrupted.
>
> "Some of them, yes. But most of the detainees are going to the Green Belt as part of the diversion. Only the most important of them will be selected for suspended animation—to wait out the ice age down here, and eventually be awakened by these caretaker machines you see around us. And there are computers to monitor the outside world and store the knowledge we’ll need when we resume our civilization."
>
> "Quite a setup," Amundson said. "But why Wisconsin? Why didn't you put the base in southern California or Texas?"
>
> Dr. Carlyle sighed as a person does when explaining elementary facts to people unacquainted with them. "During the four previous ice ages, the glaciers overran the
> upper Midwest, New England, and New York. This time we expect them to cover the entire country.
>
> "In the past, this area of Wisconsin remained unglaciated. It's called the Driftless Area. Project Odyssey is in the heart of that area.

So we have a base in Wisconsin where people will be put in suspended animation to wait out an ice age.

[image: Cover of "The Odyssey Project" showing a woman in a parka and a man in a jacket and toque with a machine pistol walking through snow in front of the U.S. Capitol which is almost buried in snow]

Comment: Nicely done, sir. Thanks!